# Advice for course homepage design

Tags: website-design

I would love some input on the UX of the website that I've been designing.

The webpage can be found at https://www.math180.coursehome.page/ -- it's purpose is to serve as the homepage for a mathematics course (not specifically calculus; this is just a placeholder course).

In particular, I am anticipating that a large portion of the users will be mobile users.

Any input and criticism (typography, navigation, etc) is appreciated!

Comment: Your list of lectures does not appear to render properly in Firefox (desktop).

Comment: @kicken, thank you, I saw that.  I solved the issue and haven't pushed the changes yet.

Comment: Thanks for the question (and interest in UX), but your question is too broad, I think - you sound like you expect a (product?) review. This community will answer specific questions where you have identified an issue, done some research, but need help to find a solution.

Comment: @virtualnobi I'm surprised at your comment.  It seems like my question was pretty straightforward: what can I improve on?  I don't have professional UX experience, so I wanted to draw upon the experience of others.

But this isn't my SE community, so fair enough.

Comment: Hi Mobius thank you for your interest in UX, what Virtualnobi means that this question is not 'future' proof. We try to create a libary that can be looked back to in the future. For instance the website in question can change in design, answers given now would become obsolete. What you could ask for instance is 'is it ok to leave out the home link and just only have the logo link to home'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of my suggestions and criticism is meant for future UX designers and developers. Your website is better than that of some of my Computer Science Professors.

**Suggestions**

1. Within "Other stuff", for each file, it would be a good idea to provide the "last updated" information. As a student, I often had to download all the files and manually compare them with the ones I already had to see if the Prof. had updated them.
2. Provide a scroll to the top button/link. It will be quite helpful to the users.

**Criticism**

1. The title "Other stuff" is severely misleading. It gives the impression that it contains unimportant content. You could rename it to "Course and Exam materials".
2. The layout of the tabs "Lectures" and "Other stuff" is mildly misleading. They give the impression of being external links(links that would redirect you out of the website). Furthermore, there is a possibility that first-time visitors might scroll down and miss them. Furthermore, some visitors might come to your website directly into specific tabs (by-passing the home page) and hence might never get to read your home page instructions. Additionally, if you want to add more such tabs in the future, you might fall short of space. The solution to all this could be to provide a collapsible, floating and scrollable sidebar instead.
3. Within "Other stuff", "Exam materials" seem to be unorganized. The difference between the font size of the heading and the font size of the sub-heading is not significant. A solution could be to increase the size difference and provide an indentation. Another solution could be to tabulate it. Yet another solution could be to make the webpage collapsible. Example: See [Outbound and Inbound](https://www.lakeheadu.ca/international/exchange)

Comment: Thank you for the input -- I'll be making the necessary changes.

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction when I landed on this page(as a designer) was, that's really well constructed. Considering your audience being scholars, you have nailed the overall tone and theme of the page, however it would be really interesting to see how this page looks when the content is populated.

However there is just one point on which I would like to comment:
 - When the user lands on your lecture page, you see the next and previous arrows at the very top. However if I had to imagine users going through this page, they would need the icons at the end of the article than at the top. I would read the article, finish it and then would want to move on to the next module(lecture).

Comment: That's a fair point.  I'll consider moving things around a bit.